# Camel case string from all caps

Tags: python, r

I have a database with many thousands of tables and columns. The column names are consistently in all caps e.g. BOOKINGPROCESSNOTEADDED, BOOKEDDATETIME, BOOKINGSTATUS. I wish to rename columns so they are lower camel case e.g. BOOKINGSTATUS -> booking_status

Because there is no variation in case between words, spaces or underscores, it's essentially impossible to apply more traditional methods to convert strings into different cases (e.g. using R's `snakecase` package). I was wondering if it's possible to instead apply some sort of English language dictionary lookup on each string and return splits.

Taking the BOOKINGSTATUS example above, a return could be: boo_king_status, boo_king_stat_us and booking_status. Specifying the minimum length of words would be useful. If the minimum is set to 4 letters, then only booking_status would be returned in this example (because 'boo' is only 3-letters long and 'us' only 2-letters long)

It's quite possible that a brute-force method is too computationally expensive, but wanted to ask in case there is a reasonably efficient method to do this. A Python or R solution would be most welcome.

Comment: Look into `string::words()` - more info here: [Extract words from a sentence](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/word.html)

Comment: How many unique column names exist?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but a few thousand, at least.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

add_spaces <- function(colnames, words) {
  for(i in 1:length(colnames)) {
    for(j in words) {
      if(str_detect(string = colnames[i], pattern = j)) {
        colnames[i] <- str_replace(string = colnames[i], j, glue::glue("{str_to_lower(j)}_"))
      }
    }
  }
 
  colnames <- colnames %>% 
    str_remove("\\_+$") # Remove hyphens at the end
  
  message("Characters not identified: ")
  print(str_remove_all(colnames, "[a-z_]"))
  
  invisible(colnames)
}
   
colnames <- names(<file>) # Capture colnames  # Using c("BOOKINGPROCESSNOTEADDED", "BOOKEDDATETIME", "BOOKINGSTATUS")

words <- c("BOOKING", "BOOKED", "PROCESS") # Create first list of words

colnames <- add_spaces(colnames, words) # Run the first iteration        

> Characters not identified:
[1] "NOTEADDED" "DATETIME"  "STATUS"

words <- c(words, "NOTE", "ADDED", "DATE", "TIME", "STATUS") # Augment list with missing words

colnames <- add_spaces(colnames, words) # Rerun, ... repeat as needed
    
colnames 

[1] "booking_process_note_added" "booked_date_time"           "booking_status"
```

Comment: I think you don't want to convert everything to lowercase first.  You're going to get `book_ing` that way if `book` is in the word list, whether it comes first or second.  It's better to keep a record of which parts have already been converted and leave those alone, and an easy way is to leave them uppercase until converted.

Comment: Good point.  Upper vs Lower case is a good way to mark what has been changed.  I fleshed out my answer to use this.  Still requires manually adding the words.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sloppy, brute-force, imperfect attempt. It will almost certainly miss something. In fact, it's more a conversation about the process, hoping that you can build a better "dictionary".

First, a discussion about this "dictionary": ideally it should contain a word and its plural, `*ing`, and `*ed` forms. We'll be attempting to replace each word with a snake-wrapped (`_word_`) version, so we'll go in reverse-order based on length. For sanity, we should probably remove too-short words (`and`, `an`, `a`), so let's start with `stringr::words` (simply a *"sample character vectors for practicing string manipulations"*, not a great start).

```r
words <- stringr::words[ order(nchar(stringr::words), decreasing = TRUE) ]
# see words[nchar(words) < 4] for what we are removing here
words <- words[nchar(words) > 3]
Reduce(function(txt, ptn) gsub(ptn, paste0("_", ptn ,"_"), txt, perl = TRUE),
       toupper(words), init = vec)
# [1] "_BOOK_ING_PROCESS__NOTE_ADDED" "_BOOK_ED_DATE__TIME_"          "_BOOK_INGSTATUS"
```

That looks odd, certainly. We can note that some of the words we *know* are in our vector are missing in `stringr::words`:

```r
c("booking", "process", "status") %in% words
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

We can augment our list:

```r
words2 <- c(words, "booking", "booked", "status")
words2 <- words2[ order(nchar(words2), decreasing = TRUE) ]
Reduce(function(txt, ptn) gsub(ptn, paste0("_", ptn ,"_"), txt, perl = TRUE),
       toupper(words2), init = vec)
# [1] "__BOOK_ING__PROCESS__NOTE_ADDED" "__BOOK_ED__DATE__TIME_"          "__BOOK_ING__STATUS_"
```

The issue here is that since we have both `"booking"` and `"book"`, it will always double-change `"BOOKING"`. Given my naïve start here, I don't know that there's an easy quick-patch other than to remove `"book"` (and `"king"`, incidentally).

```r
words3 <- setdiff(words2, c("book", "king"))
Reduce(function(txt, ptn) gsub(ptn, paste0("_", ptn ,"_"), txt, perl = TRUE),
       toupper(words3), init = vec)
# [1] "_BOOKING__PROCESS__NOTE_ADDED" "_BOOKED__DATE__TIME_"          "_BOOKING__STATUS_"
```

From here, we can remove leading/trailing and double `_`.

```r
gsub("__", "_",
     gsub("^_|_$", "", 
          Reduce(function(txt, ptn) gsub(ptn, paste0("_", ptn ,"_"), txt, perl = TRUE),
                 toupper(words3), init = vec)))
# [1] "BOOKING_PROCESS_NOTE_ADDED" "BOOKED_DATE_TIME"           "BOOKING_STATUS"
```

The quality is completely dependent on starting with a good dictionary. If all of your UPPERNOSPACEWORDS are well defined, then perhaps you can build it manually. (Note that some words may just self-isolate because there is a known word both before and after (note that `"added"` is not in `words3` but it is still broken out).

Answer (score 1):

I would build the dictionary manually:

- Start with an empty dictionary
- Get all names
- Find one containing uppercase
- Manually add words to the dictionary to split that one
- Split all of them using the current dictionary

Repeat the last 3 steps until all words are split.  For example, with the 3 names you posted, the dictionary would first get `c("booking", "status")`, and that name would have no uppercase.  The name `BOOKINGPROCESSNOTEADDED` would become `booking_PROCESSNOTEADDED`; if you chose that, you'd add `c("process", "note", "added")` to the dictionary, and find `BOOKEDDATETIME` next.  Now you need to decide on the words:  is it `c("booked", "date", "time")` or `c("booked", "datetime")`?

And so on.